# Override django admin activity log

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

How can I override django admin main page in order to hide certain activities.

For example:

I don't want the admin to see which users he created on the admin main page.I'm thinking I could override the get_queryset method like this:

```
class ActiveLogManager(models.Manager):

    get_queryset():
        entries = LogEntry.objects.exclude(content_type=4, action_flag=1)
        return entries
```

But I don't know where to place the admin manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The queryset of admin main page logs is defined by the template tag [`django.contrib.admin.templatetags.log.get_admin_log`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/log.py).

So you can override the `log` template tags library by redefining it in `yourapp/templatetags/log.py` (`yourapp` must be before `django.contrib.admin` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, so that your `log` template tags library takes the precedence over `django.contrib.admin`'s).

```
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.log import *  # noqa

def __AdminLogNode_render(self, context):
    if self.user is None:
        entries = LogEntry.objects.all()
    else:
        user_id = self.user
        if not user_id.isdigit():
            user_id = context[self.user].pk
        entries = LogEntry.objects.filter(user__pk=user_id)
    entries = entries.exclude(content_type=4, action_flag=1)
    context[self.varname] = entries.select_related('content_type', 'user')[:int(self.limit)]
    return ''
__AdminLogNode_render.__name__ = 'render'

AdminLogNode.render = __AdminLogNode_render
```

Comment: Thanks , this worked. However I had to place my app **before**  `django.contrib.admin` for the templatetag to work.